# Why parameter with property name does not retrieve object property?

Tags: javascript

This is my JavaScript code. In this code `s` is "semester1".  Now where I write `data.s` it's not getting the value of `data.semester1`, but `undefined`:

```js
function mcaBooks(s) {
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', '../json//bookmca.json', true);
    xhr.onload = function (s) {
        let data = JSON.parse(this.response);

        console.log(data.s);// giving undifined
    }
    xhr.send();
}
```

HTML:

```html
<li><b><a id="semester1" onclick="mcaBooks(this.id)">Semester 1</a></b></li>
```

JSON data:

```json
{
    "semester1": [
        "Information technology",
        "Methamatical foundation of CS",
        "Programming and problem solving in c",
        "computer organization abs assembly language programming",
        "Communication skills"
    ],
    "semester2": [
        "Operation System",
        "Database Management System",
        "Data Structure",
        "Computer Oriented Numerical & statistical Methods",
        "Accounts & Management Control"
    ]
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It should be `data[s]`

Comment: `data.s` is the same as `data["s"]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few issues:

- The `onload` callback receives a ProgressEvent object as first argument, which is not something you are interested in
- The name you have given to the `onload` parameter is hiding the parameter of your `mcaBooks` function, which has the same name `s`.
- `data.s` would look for a property named "s" (literal). Instead you want a dynamic property look up: `data[s]`.

Some other remarks:

- The double `//` in the URL looks suspicious. Is that really correct?
- Use a more descriptive variable name. `s` doesn't really tell us much.

So it should be:

```
function mcaBooks(semester) { // <--- better name
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', '../json//bookmca.json', true);
    xhr.onload = function () { // <--- remove the parameter
        let data = JSON.parse(this.response);
        console.log(data[semester]); // <--- dynamic property reference
    }
    xhr.send();
}
```

Finally, using `XMLHttpRequest` for this is really old-style. You can do this much easier with `fetch`:

```
async function mcaBooks(semester) {
    let response = await fetch('../json//bookmca.json');
    let data = await response.json();
    console.log(data[semester]);
}
```

Comment: Agree with using fetch instead, but if xhr is being used then you can also set the `xhr.responseType = 'json'` to make it easier